# How to set read/write permission on database in phpmyadmin?

Tags: database, permissions, phpmyadmin, readonly, read-write

I am working on a wordpress site where no one is able to access the dashboard because the database has been set to readonly. I have access to phpmyadmin, but I can't figure out how to change the database back to read/write.

As far as I can tell, I have full privileges (eg, I can modify the tables, and I created a new admin account successfully)

I have tried using the query:

`USE master;

GO

ALTER DATABASE databasename

SET READ_WRITE;

GO`

but I get the error

> ## 1044 - Access denied for user 'xxx'@'localhost' to database 'master'

Is this the right thing to do to change the permissions for the msql database, or am I barking up the wrong tree? If it's the right tree, is it just a case of getting root access?

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance,

Yukon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using CPanel as well go to the MySQL section and change the privileges for the user, just to make sure enable all of them to make sure that it is not a privilege problem. Also check that the username you are using in the connection is correct.

Comment: Thanks Eddy. turns out I didn't successfully create the admin account through Phpadmin. It looked good, but when I used an existing account and changed the password through the database, it worked! Thanks for your help.